# BeautifulSoup4 [] output error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project in which I use beautifulsoup4 to take certain parts of a website. I am using the website "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL&guccounter=1", and I want to take the big number that is displayed as the current stock price. When I do inspect element of this number I get:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">186.31</span>
```

In my program, I currently have the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
numbers = soup.find_all("span", {"class"}: {"data-reactid"})
```

When I print "numbers" I get the output []. What am I getting wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the full code for reference:

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

root = Tk()

root.title("Stock Price")
root.configure(background="white")

Calculator = Frame(root, height=300, width=500, bg="white").grid(column=0, row=2)
title = Label(root, bg="white", text="Stock Price Calculator", font="Sans 25 bold", fg="black").grid(row=0)

Stock_ticker = Label(root, text="Input stock ticker here:", font="Sans 18 bold")
Stock_ticker.place(x=7, y=60)
Ticker_entry = Entry(root, width=10)
Ticker_entry.place(x=235, y=64)

Stock_price = Label(root, text="Current stock price:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_price.place(x=7, y=100)

Stock_price_output = Entry(root, width=10)
Stock_price_output.place(x=160, y=100)

Stock_price_day = Label(root, text="Opening price for the day:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_price_day.place(x=7, y=140)

Stock_price_day_output = Entry(root, width=10)
Stock_price_day_output.place(x=195, y=141)

Stock_news = Label(root, text="News about stock:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_news.place(x=7, y=180)

Stock_news_output1 = Entry(root, width=30)
Stock_news_output1.place(x=150, y=181)

Stock_news_output2 = Entry(root, width=30)
Stock_news_output2.place(x=150, y=210)

Stock_news_output3 = Entry(root, width=30)
Stock_news_output3.place(x=150, y=239)


Submit = Button(root, text="Submit", font="Sans 14", command = lambda: Calculation())
Submit.place(x=165, y=270)

Reset = Button(root, text="Reset", font="Sans 14", command = lambda: Cleaning(Ticker_entry, Stock_price_output, Stock_price_day_output, Stock_news_output1, Stock_news_output2, Stock_news_output3))
Reset.place(x=250, y=270)


def make_url(ticker_symbol):
    return "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/history?p=%s" % (ticker_symbol, ticker_symbol)

def Calculation():
    stock = Ticker_entry.get()
    url = make_url(stock)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    numbers = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "data-reactid"})
    print(numbers)



def Cleaning(writing_area1, writing_area2, writing_area3, writing_area4, writing_area5, writing_area6):
        writing_area1.delete(0, END)
        writing_area2.delete(0, END)
        writing_area3.delete(0, END)
        writing_area4.delete(0, END)
        writing_area5.delete(0, END)
        writing_area6.delete(0, END)
```

The issue occurs when I click the button "Submit", meaning when it runs the function "Calculation"

Comment: That's not even valid syntax. Please show the actual code you have used.

Comment: Here is the full code:  page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    numbers = soup.find_all("div")
    print(numbers)

Comment: Don't provide details in the comments, edit your answer

Comment: @averroes I didn't. How do I format the list as a string?

Comment: I count at least three things wrong here. 1) invalid syntax 2) searching for a div when you want a span 3) searching for a class instead of an attribute 4) code in the comments doesn't match what's in the question

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi, I am searching for a span. Also, what do you mean by attribute? What am I supposed to search for? Thanks a lot

Comment: You keep changing the code you are supposedly using. And it's still not even valid Python syntax. Why couldn't you have copied the actual code in the first place?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The one that is there is the actual code.